# laravelpassport socialite provider throwing GuzzleHttp RequestException cURL error 3

Tags: laravel, guzzle, laravel-passport, php-curl, laravel-socialite

##### Laravel Framework version: 8.69.0

I have installed laravelpassport socialite provider following this documentation: https://socialiteproviders.com/Laravel-Passport/#installation-basic-usage

'/auth/passport-redirect' works fine. But it throws error on '/auth/passport-callback' GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException
cURL error 3: (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for /oauth/token

##### [Note: I have successfully configured Google and Auth0 provider without any issues. But laravelpassport isn't working]

Here is a screenshot of the Error screen: https://ibb.co/c2Y97HV

[image: Here is a screenshot of the Error screen]

Here is my code:

[image: Here is my code]

Comment: Have you added the correct info in your .env file? Also I see that you said google, so the driver would be google not laravelpassport. Here's a link to google provider https://socialiteproviders.com/Google-Plus/

Comment: @EricEvans I meant to say that Google, Facebook, LinkedIn, Auth0, Instagram, etc. providers are working fine. But laravelpassport provider isn't working. Regarding .env file: Yes, I have added required variables there. Also, updated config/services.php file and updated listener in app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php file as documented. /auth/passport-redirect works fine and shows oAuth user consent page but when it redirects to the /auth/passport-callback page to retrieve user data, it shows that Error.

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you find a resolution?